# Python Shell Ask For a File name, then ask for a substring (any) and the program will output the # of occurrences

Tags: python, input

So I need to write a program, that asks me to input a file name, then to input any word, and it gives me an output of how many words there are in a separate text file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
fname= raw_input("Enter File Name: ")
s= raw_input("enter substring: ")

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

One more line:

```
print f.read().count(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have so far is a good start. In fact, it's almost exactly what I would have started with if I were solving the problem myself. Since this is probably a homework assignment, I'm not going to write the code for you, but hopefully I can point you towards what to do next.

First off, you'll want to read the file into a string that you can search through. Probably you'll want to use `f.read()` to get this all at once. You could alternatively process one line at a time, but I think that will not work if your search string spans more than one of them.

You may need to do some "cleaning" of the string before searching (e.g. regularizing whitespace, capitalization, punctuation, etc.). How much of this you need may depend on exactly what the contents of your file is, and how tightly you want the search to work. If you search for "ill" do you want it to match "I'll"? How about "hyphenated" matching "hyphen-\nated" (if your text file has hyphens splitting words between two lines)?

Once you have the cleaned string, you have to decide how to search for the substring. You can either use methods of the `str` class (such as `find` or `count`), or you could use a module like `re` that does more advanced text searching. Read the docs and pick whichever seems most appropriate to you.

Comment: Not a homework assignment, it's a question in the textbook (optional) but Its making me mad -_- I'm trying that but still no success :/

Comment: If you've tried some more stuff, edit it into the original question so we can see where you're going wrong and help out.

Comment: Okay! I'm going to bed now, will go at it tomorrow. Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0):

```
// read the file into a list
// split each line into words
// compare each word with the desired word and count
import string
fname = raw_input("Enter File Name: ")
s     = raw_input("enter substring: ")
fp    = open(fname, 'rt')
L     = fp.readlines()    # read all lines into a list "L"
c     = 0                 # word count
for i in L:
    arr = string.split(i) # split on whitespace
    for word in arr:
        if word == s:
            c += 1
print "There are %d occurrances of the word \"%s\" in file \"%s\"\n" % (c, s, fname)
```

Comment: If you're going to iterate over the lines, you don't need to use `readlines` first. Just iterate directy on `fp`. Also, you can use the `i.split` method rather than grabbing the equivalent function from the `string` module.